# Rss Reader (aggregator) based on google reader

Tags: c#, javascript, google-reader

I have created an RSS reader (web-app), with usual stuff read rss in xml format parse and display it to user. Every thing is working fine.
Now I want 'my reader app' to use google-reader account as back end, my work flow goes like this

1. Ask user to log into google account (through pop window).
2. Google ask user-Id password and after login it says " 'xyz' app want to access you acount 'Allow' 'Deny'"
3. After allow, access google reader account and get list of subscriptions
4. If user reads a feed tell google reader (may be thru web API), this item has been read

I just dont know how to accomplish this part. I have tried googling and have read many posts/blog but nothing worked i dont know from where to start.

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [this blog post from Martin Doms](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/), you should be able to get a session token using an `HttpWebRequest` object with an URL like:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?service=reader&Email=me@gmail.com&Passwd=pass
```

The whole blog (the article is composed of 3 parts) is worth reading to have a complete overview of the approach.

You can also read about the Google Reader API on [this site](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI).